# Web-Scraping of tables within a timetable

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am fairly new to web-scraping but as part of a project I am working on im trying to scrape details of classes from this timetable https://www101.dcu.ie/timetables/feed.php?prog=case&per=2&week1=19&week2=30&day=7&hour=1-20&template=Studprog 
I'm going to try use jsoup but amen't sure how exactly to parse the data in the way that would return only the relevant information. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iconv` and `cheerio`.

I made a functional example for you to see:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const getRequestDefault = (method) => (url) => 
    rp({
        encoding: null,
        method: method,
        uri: url,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    })
        .then(html => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(
                iconv.decode(
                    new Buffer(html), "ISO-8859-1"
                )
            );

            return $;
        })

const getRows = () => 
    getRequestDefault('GET')(`https://www101.dcu.ie/timetables/feed.php?prog=case&per=2&week1=19&week2=30&day=7&hour=1-20&template=Studprog`)
        .then($ => {
            // Example
            $('table tbody tr')
                .toArray()
                .forEach(
                    a => {
                        console.log($(a).text());
                    }
                );
        });

getRows();
```

This is going to scrape all the fields `tr` of all the tables.

You can use this as a starting point. Just copy the code into a .js file, install the dependencies and use:
`node file.js`

To install the dependencies:
`npm install cheerio iconv request request-promise`

I hope it helps you

Comment: thank you for the help ill go with what you've outlined above

Comment: No problem! If you served, you can set the answer as the correct answer!

Comment: I've been looking into cheerio, do you know any good sites where i could learn more?